# Screen Brightness wont change Ubuntu 18.04 Intel

Tags: intel-graphics, brightness, backlight

Cant change the brightness with keys or through the bar on the top right.

ive changed my `/usr/X11/xorg.conf.d/FILEHERE`
multiple times with different given solutions and each one breaks my computer to command line only.

Ive made changes to my /etc/default/grub to include/change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
```

And even tried adding a backlight file (to which i get a not allowed error even running in sudo), on.

```
/sys/class/backlight
```

but since I am not allowed i am all that is in my /sys/class is

```
.              drm             mdio_bus      printer       tpm
..             drm_dp_aux_dev  mei           ptp           tpmrm
ata_device     extcon          mem           pwm           tty
ata_link       firmware        misc          rapidio_port  usb_role
ata_port       gpio            mmc_host      regulator     vc
backlight      graphics        nd            rfkill        vfio
bdi            hidraw          net           rtc           video4linux
block          hmm_device      pci_bus       scsi_device   virtio-ports
bluetooth      hwmon           pci_epc       scsi_disk     vtconsole
bsg            i2c-adapter     phy           scsi_generic  watchdog
devcoredump    i2c-dev         powercap      scsi_host     wmi_bus
devfreq        ieee80211       power_supply  sound
devfreq-event  input           ppdev         spi_master
dma            iommu           ppp           spi_slave
dmi            leds            pps           thermal
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

ps: Sorry about the my wining, Just annoyed with breaking my computer multiple times while being blinded by my max light laptop monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with `echo 4 | sudo tee -a  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`
Odd since my backlight file/folder wasnt there before, but it's working great for me.